# Given a text and a list of words from that text, how to 'map' the words back to the text and find the most likely start locations of each word?

Tags: algorithm, text, matching

## Lets suppose I have the following text:

> "This is a paragraph. In this paragraph there are words. Some of the words, like words and paragraph, can be repeated. I also have a list of words that I need to map."

## And the following list of words (can be in any order, caps don't matter):

> this, paragraph, in, paragraph, there, words, some, words, like, words, and, paragraph, can, be, repeated, also, have, list, words, need, map

---

I want to find a mapping from the word in the list to its likely location in the text, that maximizes the words from the list that are used up. You could think of it as trying to reassemble a piece of text from the underlying words, or trying put back a puzzle (where not all of the pieces are present).

In the example above, the matching would look something like:

this->0

paragraph->10

in->21

paragraph->28

there->38

words->48 (or location of other 'words')

And so on for other members of the list.

Is there a matching algorithm that can help out with this task? Could it be extended to just finding binary data using a list of binary data fragments?

Comment: It looks like an n^2 runtime no matter what. Iterate through your dictionary whilst iterating through the paragraph. When a compareTo is satisfied increment that words value. Even if you sorted... same... even if you eliminated values that you know didn't exist in the paragraph by finding the highest integer count in your dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem known as [Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). Consider the text also as a sequence of words. You have to find a sequence that is contained in both original sequences with maximum length.

There are O(n*m) solutions to this problem. The dynamic programming solution is to easiest to understand.

Comment: I considered this algorithm, but I believe that it works only if the sequences are in the same order (in my example they are, but as I mentioned in the question, the order of the list can be completely arbitrary).

Comment: So isn't it just a matter of counting how many times a word appears in the text? This a much easier problem, so.